# Does the following series converge uniformly on $(0,+\infty)$?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, functions, uniform-convergence, sequence-of-function

I would like you to take a look at the following function-series. This is a problem I came across in Real Analysis some months ago and I had left it aside, but then I forgot about it. Note that Weierstrass's criterion is not applicable here and I can't seem to find a factorization that would make either Abel's or Dirichlet's criterion applicable.

$\displaystyle{s(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}2^n\sin\left(\frac{1}{3^nx}\right)}$, for $x \in (0,+\infty)$. By the $\sin(x)<x$ inequality, it is obvious that it converges pointwise. It is also quite obvious that it converges uniformly in any $[\alpha,+\infty)$, where $\alpha>0$. What about $(0,+\infty)$ though?

Comment: Eerily similar: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2289247/explore-uniform-convergence-of-function-series :)

Comment: Hello, I am the guy who posted the wrong answer on this one. I ran through my notes on real analysis and found the exercise, I figured I should give this problem some more rep.

Comment: I noticed -- I added the link above for indexing purposes.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let $f_n(x) = 2^n \sin \frac{1}{3^nx}$. If the series were uniformly convergent on $(0,+\infty)$, then we'd have uniform convergence of $(f_n)$ to $0$. But

$$f_n(3^{-n}) = 2^n \sin 1$$

is unbounded.